# Named param not being detected

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a simple query as follows. I get the expected result if I hard code the id value as follows. But it throws IllegalArgumentException exception if I try to get the value from the Param instead. Note that I have tried to use the Param as both long and String and still the same results. Please advise what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

My Query

```
public interface FeedDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<FeedDetail, Long> {
    @Query("select fd.message from FeedDetail as fd where fd.feedId =: id")
    String custom(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

At Controller, if I run the following, I get an exception.

```
@GetMapping("/something/{id}")
    public String getDetail(@PathVariable long id){
        return feedDetailRepository.custom(id);
    }
```

But if I hard code the id value as follows, I get the wanted result.

```
public interface FeedDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<FeedDetail, Long> {
    @Query("select fd.message from FeedDetail as fd where fd.feedId = 4")
    String getDetailBasedOnFeedId(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

The exception

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : id

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would change

```
 @Query("select fd.message from FeedDetail as fd where fd.feedId =: id")
```

To (difference lies in space)

```
 @Query("select fd.message from FeedDetail as fd where fd.feedId = :id")
```

This is a small difference for you but big for Spring. He recognizes a parameter by attaching name to colon like that

> :id

For more details refer to the [official Spring Data JPA Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

**Wrong query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` as c where c.driver_one = :id OR c.driver_two = **:id;**
```

**Correct query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` as c where c.driver_one = :id OR c.driver_two = **:id**
```

Answer (score -1):

This is likely because of the way you have provided space with in the query.
My suggestion would be to format the code and in the string quotes use something similar

```sql
SELECT fd.message from FeedDetail AS fd where fd.feedId = :id
```

Comment: What is the difference from Emil Hotkowski's answer?